# Item not being selected and updated from react-native-dropdown-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using a React-native-dropdown-picker in order to show a list of dates, however when I select on any item the value is not being selected

[image]

the complete code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {getMonthDate} from '../../../utils/dateUtils';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {getFullDate} from '../../../utils/dateUtils';
import DaysInAWeek from './DaysInAWeek';
export default function Header(props) {
  const [daysInAWeek, setDaysInAWeek] = useState([]);
  const data = props.data;
  // const end_ts = props.end_ts;
  // const start_ts = props.start_ts;
  const end_ts = 1605916800000;
  const start_ts = 1603238400000;

  let interval = 7 * 86400000;
  let arr = [];
  let new_arr = [];
  for (let i = start_ts; i < end_ts; i = i + interval) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    new_arr.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2));
  }

  let dateArr = [];

  for (let a of new_arr) {
    console.log('a', a);
    let label;
    if (a.length > 1) {
      label = getMonthDate(new Date(a[0])) + '-' + getMonthDate(new Date(a[1]));
    } else {
      label = `${getMonthDate(new Date(a[0]))}`;
    }
    let obj = {
      label,
      value: a,
    };
    dateArr.push(obj);
  }

  function onValSelect(val) {
    if (val.length > 1) {
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = val[0]; i <= val[1]; i += 86400000) {
        let date = getMonthDate(new Date(i));
        arr.push(date);
      }

      console.log('final arr', arr);
      setDaysInAWeek(arr);
    } else {
      console.log('single date', new Date(val));
      setDaysInAWeek(new Date(val));
    }
  }

  console.log('date Arr', dateArr);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {console.log('new array', dateArr)}
        {console.log('arr', arr)}
        <Icon
          name="arrow-left"
          size={20}
          color="#fff"
          style={{marginTop: 12}}
        />
        {console.log('----------date', dateArr)}
        {dateArr != null && (
          <DropDownPicker
            onChangeItem={value=>{
              onValSelect(value)
            }}
            items={dateArr}
            itemStyle={{
              // justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              flexDirection:'row'
            }}
            
            containerStyle={{height: 40,width:'80%',zIndex:2}}
          />
        )}
        {console.log('----------days', daysInAWeek)}
        
      </View>
      <DaysInAWeek daysInAWeek={daysInAWeek} />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
    // height: 56,
    zIndex:2,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "when I select on any item the value is not being selected" - seems a bit oxymoronic, can you explain what is, or isn't, selected? What debugging steps have you taken? Are there any error logs? Is `onValSelect` invoked? If so, does it have the expected `val` value? What is all the array looping in the function body for? Looks to be mostly constructing the options for the picker? Also, I see are a date object is saved into state versus keeping it an array (`setDaysInAWeek(new Date(val));`).

Comment: onValSelect is not getting invoked, that is the issue and I have tried removing all the other items in the view consoled the state but the method is not being invoked at all, very weird but am unsure of the reason

Comment: Think you could create a running [Expo snack](https://expo.io/) that reproduces this issue?